# How to deploy  sharepoint groups

Tags: wspbuilder

Is there any way to deploy some custom sharepoint groups in my WSPBuilder project?

Or how can I avoid to make groups manually during the installation of my application?

Answer (score 1):

you could think of a site collection feature event receiver that creates the required sharepoint groups in your site.

Just create a feature with site collection scope and add a feature receiver that gets the site collection reference and adds the sharepoint groups.

- Sudhir